# How can I test that the default cache is working correctly?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, full-page-cache

I changed "Enable External Cache" to "no" and flush the cache for a few mins to see if that effected loading times, but they were about the same. Is that an effective way of testing if the cache is being using?

(I know the cache files are being created ok, I can see them in FTP, I just suspect that they are not being used when loading the pages)

Comment: this option if i remember correctly for Zend Server, when cache options are configured in zend server control panel???

Comment: Do you have ssh access?

Comment: sr_magento:  yes I do.

Comment: ADM:  yes it's "Zend Full Page Cache", but I don't know where the control panel for zend server is, and there is little doc online about it (in relation to magento).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about the "External Full Page Cache", which is not what one would consider the default Magento cache. It has nothing to do with block caching and the other cache types in "System > Cache Management" which store cache files in `var/cache`.

The **external** full page cache only works if you are running the Zend Server with its cache extension. You won't see anything of it "in FTP".

Read more: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/system-operations/cache-page-external.html

Answer (score 0):

Use any page speed test to compare the loading time with and without cache on. If you use Firefox you can install the addon Firebug.

Comment: That's what I I have been using to measure TTFB, So measuring is not the issue. I need to know if I'm the method to test if the cache is being used or not is correct

Answer (score 0):

Could you output a dynamic timestamp on your page (with milliseconds) so that a refresh shows whether it's changed? You could use HTML comments (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp) if you don't want to publicly show any timestamps on your public site.

Be sure to use a Magento block that actually gets cached. The base template files, such as 1column.phtml, aren't part of the caching.

Comment: so elements like cms pages, static blocks , catagory discriptions all should be cached?  so if I put a dynamic time stamp in them that would be a good test? Thanks